# File I/O Python Save and Read

Tags: python, file-io

I need to save a dictionary and then be able to read the dictionary after it's been saved.

This is what I have and it should work (i think), but i keep getting the following error when it comes to the `read_dict` function:
`return dict(line.split() for line in x)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`
Any advice?

`def save_dict(dict1):`

```
with open('save.txt', 'w') as fh:
    for key in dict1.keys():
        fh.write(key + '' + dictionary1[key] + '\n')
```

`def readDB():`

```
with open('save.txt', 'r') as fh:
    return dict(new.split() for new in fh)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you actually need a line-by-line list in the file, use something like json or pickle to save the dict. These formats deal with things like spaces in the key name, non-string values, non-ascii characters and such.

```
import json
dict1 = {'test':123}
with open('save.txt', 'w') as fh:
    json.dump(dict1, fh)
with open('save.txt', 'r') as fh:
    dict2 = json.load(fh)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use space instead of empty string, otherwise `str.split` will return a single item list which is going to raise an error when passed to `dict()`.

```
fh.write(key + ' ' + dictionary1[key] + '\n')
```

Or better use string formatting:

```
for key, val in dict1.items():
    fh.write('{} {}\n'.format(key, val))
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> s = 'k' + '' + 'v'     #WRONG
>>> s
'kv'
>>> s.split()     
['kv']

>>> s = 'k' + ' ' + 'v'    #RIGHT
>>> s
'k v'
>>> s.split()
['k', 'v']
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Simple mistake. Nice eyes.

Comment: @user3014014 Glad that helped, feel free to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) when the  system allows you to.

Comment: this is rather fragile. It will fail if key or value have spaces in them. Perhaps use '=' as a separator?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use pickle module man!
Check out this example :

```
## Importing
from pickle import dump

## You make the dictionary
my_dict = {'a':1 , 'b':2 , 'c':3}

## You dump the dictionary's items to a binary (.txt file for windows)
with open('the path you want to save','wb') as da_file:
    dump(my_dict , da_file)
```

save that file as "something0.py"

```
## Importing
from pickle import load

## You getting the data back from file
## the variable that will get the result of load module
## will be the same type with the variable that "dumped"
## the items to that file!
with open('the file path which you will get the items from' , 'rb') as da_file:
    my_dict = load(da_file)

## Print out the results
from pprint import pprint
pprint(my_dict)
```

save that file as "something1.py"

Now run the two modules with the same file on "with" statement,
first 0 then 1 .
And 1 will print you the same results that the 0 gave to the file!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you should use pickle, but as a more simplified way

```
FileTowriteto = open("foo.txt", "wb")
import pickle
DumpingDict = {"Foo":"Foo"}
pickle.dump(DumpingDict, FileTowriteto)
```

Then when you want to read it you can do this

```
OldDict = open("foo.txt", "rb")
OldDictRecover = pickle.load(OldDict)
```

This should work, and if the output is binary run the str() function on it.